# Using Flet in Pythonista on iOS

Tags: python, pythonista, flet

I'm playing around with [Flet](https://flet.dev/) on macOS. It's pretty cool when you want to develop a UI in Python -- on macOS.

Is there a way to use Flet code in [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/) on iOS?

Comment: The flet environment is python3.7 or higher. See [here](https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/getting-started)

Comment: @r-beginners Pythonista uses currently Python 3.10 (see [here](https://apps.apple.com/es/app/pythonista-3/id1085978097?l=en)), so that would match.

Comment: So the latest version supports 3.10. I did not know. No further answers are available to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*there is no official way to run flet source code on ios.*

flet, for now, only has the ability to be run on computers(i.e., windows, linux, mac). the only way to view the app in ios is to download the flet app which was release 3 months ago and use the computer to run the code.

the way to do so, is to run the flet app in the computer with the command:

`flet run --ios`

which will give u a QR code to scan. when u scan it and open the link in flet app,
u can view the app in ios.

**Note:**

when i said that flet can only run on computers, i mean when not compiled to run on android and ios, support for which was release few months back.

**links:**

https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/testing-on-ios/

https://flet.dev/blog/flet-for-ios

Comment: Thanks @VivekanandaMullangi. Makes total sens. The link to the blog post is helpful too.